# HashMap - insertion type error

Tags: c++, templates

In my main method, the following code has an error at the line containing the insertion.

```
hashTable<string, pair<string, string>> friendsHash = hashTable<string, pair<string, string>>(friendTotal);
        if(critChoice == 1)
        {
            for(int counter = 0; counter < friendTotal; counter ++)
            {
                string name = friends[counter].getName();
                string date = friends[counter].getBirthDate();
                string homeTown = friends[counter].getHomeTown();
                friendsHash.insert(pair<name, pair<date, homeTown>>);
            }
        }
```

The hashMap's insertion function is as follows:

```
template<class K, class E>
void hashTable<K, E>::insert(const pair<const K, E>& thePair)
{
    int b = search(thePair.first);

    //check if matching element found
    if(table[b] == NULL)
    {
        //no matching element and table not full
        table[b] = new pair<const K, E> (thePair);
        dSize ++;
    }
    else
    {//check if duplicate or table full
        if(table[b]->first == thePair.first)
        {//duplicate, change table[b]->second
            table[b]->second = thePair.second;
        }
        else //table is full
            throw hashTableFull();
    }
}
```

The error is that each of the 3 arguments in the insertion function call `is not a valid template type argument for parameter`

Comment: First line can be shortened to `hashTable<string, pair<string, string>> friendsHash(friendTotal);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are muddling the syntax for instantiating a class template to get a type, with that for instantiating a type to get an object.

```
pair<name, pair<date, homeTown>>
```

should be

```
make_pair(name, make_pair(date, homeTown))
```

or if you can use C++11

```
{name, {date, homeTown}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
friendsHash.insert(pair<name, pair<date, homeTown>>);
```

you are providing the value of some variables as *template arguments* to the class template `pair<>`. This is a fundamental misconception: template argument must be known at compile-time. Therefore, they can't be variables.

However, here what you are probably trying to do is not to specify the correct instantiation of the `pair<>` class template (which would be `pair<string, pair<string, string>>`, but rather to generate an *instance* of that type.

Thus, you most likely want to change that line into:

```
friendsHash.insert(make_pair(name, make_pair(date, homeTown)));
```

The helper function template `make_pair<>()` is able to *deduce* the type of its arguments and produce the correct instantiation of `pair<>`, relieving you from the burden of explicitly specifying the template arguments.